# Adding another clickable element to existing toggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

Currently, clicking #menubutton toggles between these two functions (it slides a menu in and out). How can I close this menu by not only clicking #menubutton again but also by clicking anywhere on #page?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Dwjd/

```
$(function(){
    $('#menubutton').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        });
    function handler1(){
        $("#menubutton").css("color","red");
        $("#menu").animate({left:"0"},150);
        $("#page").animate({left:"300px"},150);
        $("#menubutton").one("click",handler2);
        }
    function handler2(){
        $("#menubutton").css("color","blue");
        $("#menu").animate({left:"-300px"},150);
        $("#page").animate({left:"0"},150);
        $("#menubutton").one("click",handler1);
        }
    $("#menubutton").one("click", handler1);
    });
```

Comment: Why do you keep binding and unbinding the click handler?

Comment: Explain what the better practice is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$('#page').click(handler2);` and setting `e.stopPropagation();` on the event for #menubutton. This will stop the #page event from triggering if you click on the link.

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/3Dwjd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use css class to indicate open `menu` element:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#page.open', handler2);

    $('#menubutton').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $page = $("#page");
            if ($page.hasClass('open')) {
                handler2();
            } else {
                handler1();
            }
            return false;
        });

    function handler1(){
            $("#menubutton").css("color","red");
            $("#menu").animate({left:"0"},150);
            $("#page").animate({left:"300px"},150).addClass('open');
        }
    function handler2(){
            $("#menubutton").css("color","blue");
            $("#menu").animate({left:"-300px"},150);
            $("#page").animate({left:"0"},150).removeClass('open');
        }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Dwjd/2/